# Setting text to a TextView in Fragment A after adding and removing Fragment B

Tags: android

I have fragment A, on TextView click I add another Fragment B, I want to update the TextView of Fragment A when I remove Fragment B, any ideas on how to do that?

Comment: Are you adding Fragment B ontop of Fragment A?

Comment: @busted13 use boolean for that

Comment: @azizbekian yes

Comment: @ShubhankGupta what would a boolean do? or where do I check with the flag? Fragment A doesn't go on pause/onresume state

Comment: Why don't you update that value before adding fragment?

Comment: @azizbekian cause I'm getting the new values from Fragment B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shubhank Gupta mentioned use a boolean when you remove `Fragment B` set it true and in `Fragement A` `onResume()` check for that boolean if it is true then change the text.

In Fragment B when removing it:

```
isTextChange = true;
```

In Fragment A:

```
 @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(isTextChange){
        mTextView.setText("Text you want");
        isTextChange = false;
        }
}
```

**Edit:**

or you can override isUserVisibleHint() method inside Fragment A and check there.

```
@Override
 public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
     super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
     if (isVisibleToUser) {
        if(isTextChange){
            mTextView.setText("Text you want");
            isTextChange = false;
          }
        } 
  }
```

Comment: Fragment A doesn't call onResume/ on Pause

Comment: @AbidKhan thanks you are quick :)

Comment: @busted13 it is override method

Comment: @busted13 onResume() will be called automatically when your fragment is visible to you after coming back.  Try to read life cycle for fragments and activities

Comment: @AbidKhan I did, and i went for this solution before posting the question. but for some reason the onResume was never called when going back to fragment A,

Comment: The fragments onResume() or onPause() will be called only when the Activities onResume() or onPause() is called. They are tightly coupled to the Activity.

Comment: @busted13 see my edit.